# ViewBag reads in characters in view

Tags: asp.net, razor

I'm using a ViewBag in my view and have found that it will read in characters from the view if they immediately follow a read of a ViewBag property i.e.

```
<input type="hidden" name="client" value=@(@ViewBag.myVal)/>
```

Given myVal has a value of "somevalue" the ViewBag property will resolve to "somevalue/". Adding a space after the ViewBag or enclosing it in double quotes fixes the issue.

Does this happen because ViewBag properties are not resolved until runtime? It seems to understand the the ">" is the closing bracket and does not append that to the string.

thanks

Comment: That's the risk you run when you don't quote attributes in HTML. Also, you don't need the `/` for the `input` (in HTML anyway -- you do if you're using XHTML, but then you'd need to quote all your attributes too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you should have double quotation marks around HTML attribute values:

```
<input type="hidden" name="client" value="@(@ViewBag.myVal)"/>
```

This prevents the issue you are describing. Since you aren't defining the closing of the attribute value specifically, .NET is picking up the / as part of it. As @HereticMonkey pointed out, you don't need the closing slash anyway. But, you should put quotes around your values regardless. If you have a space in your value, it'll break at the space where you don't want it to. For example, if myValue = "My Client Name", you'll end up with a rendered tag like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="client" value=My Client Name/>
```

Which, as you can guess, will end up posting back a value of just "My" because the space designates the end of the attribute. Put quotes around it.

Comment: I understand why the code was initially wrong and how to fix it. My question was why is the '/' interpreted as being part of the string?

Comment: When you don't use double quote marks to delineate a string, it looks for other things to determine if the string is done. It looks for a space (which you don't have) or a closing tag bracket. It does not consider a slash a closing symbol. I would guess because it's optional in HTML5 now, but I'm not certain.